# Iterating through a tree structure

Tags: actionscript-3

So suppose I have some kind of tree structure with nodes and children. I want to travel through the tree and shout when I see certain nodes.

Look at the following, this is ActionScript but it's similar to Java etc:

```
for(var i:int=0; i<parent.children.length; i++)
{ 
  child = parent.children[i];
  if(child.nodeName == "A")
  {
    parent = child;
    for(var j:int=0; j<parent.children.length; j++) 
    {
      child = parent.children[j];
      if(child.nodeName == "B")
      {
        trace("B found");
        parent = child;
        //now search for C etc...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem comes with the 'parent = child' line, I want to "jump" into then next set of children, but of course when I go back up I've lost the reference to the parent above. What's the usual method of going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion is a beautiful thing for trees:

```
public function walkTree(node:Tree)
{
    //here is where you want to check the node's name against your list of
    //'nodes to shout out about'
    trace("Node found: " + node.nodeName);


    for(var i:int=0; i < node.children.length; i++)
    {
        walkTree(node.children[i]);
    } 
}
```

**Note:** Recursion is dangerous if one of the children node can have its parent (*or its parent's parent, or its parent's parent's parent, etc*) because it will get caught in a loop. When using recursion, ensure that no child ever references a parent node.

Answer (score 1):

Make a recursive function that will traverse the tree and check nodes?

Some code :

```
public function traverse(parent:Node, node:Node, search:Array):void
{

    if (search.indexOf(node.nodeName) != -1)
        trace("Found " + node.nodeName);

    for(var i:int=0; i < node.children.length; i++)
    {
        traverse(node,node.children[i],search);
    }
}
```